# Checkbox looks different in IE and Chrome

Tags: internet-explorer, checkbox

Checkbox looks different in IE and Firefox. Need to look it consistent like Firefox. I have tried giving the css below but in IE it still doesnt show shadow inside checkbox like in FF

```
{ background-color: #FAFAFA;
border: 1px solid #CACECE;
border-radius: 3px 3px 3px 3px;
box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05), 0 -15px 10px -12px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05) inset;}
```

Any inputs?

Thanks.

Comment: Which versions of IE and Firefox are you working with?  I would expect the browsers to render differently.

Comment: IE 9 and Firefox 18.0. But in few sites, it they both looks same, so figuring out how?:)